# creating a user in ORACLE 18c ORA-04045 error after CONNECT permission granted

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

Not very familiar with oracle, was trying to practice a bit but reached a wall. I create a user with the following code

```
 CREATE USER labuser
     IDENTIFIED BY abc123
     DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
     TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
     QUOTA 10M on users
     PROFILE default;
```

And I also GRANTED CONNECT  to the user object.
but i get an error when trying to login via SQL plus. ive tried to see whats on the web but i cant find something relevant to SYSTEM.LOGONSUCCESS. do i need to grant another permission ?

[image]

[image]

dropped and retried the create to make sure i was making the local user in samplescdb.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you the DBA for this database (e.g. did you install it), or is someone else?  `LOGONSUCCESS` isn't a standard Oracle trigger - it's not in my Oracle 18c XE database - so I'm afraid this problem is something specific to your database.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is because you're trying to connect to the CDB instead of the PDB. Almost all of your work should be done on a PDB.

Comment: def connecting to the PDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE - had to execute this command in sql developer.

Grant administer database trigger to labuser;

Thank you Ed for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

When you grant `CONNECT` Role to the user then you also have to enable it. Quickest way is

```
ALTER USER labuser DEFAULT ROLE ALL;
```

In order to enable all roles by default, i.e. enabled at logon.

Comment: not so.  Unfortuntately, the limited capability of 'comments' here on SO prevent me from posting a proof.  Just try it for yourself.  Connect as a DBA, and issue these three commands -- and _only_ these three commands:  CREATE USER FRED IDENTIFIED BY FRED;  GRANT CONNECT TO FRED; CONNECT FRED/FRED; (using a local connection so as to not need to add tns service names -- strictly for simplicity)

Comment: added screenshot to post

Comment: That's strange, you created user "labuser" but you cannot alter user "labuser" afterwards. Is it the same database? Did you make a typo?

Comment: i was logged into sql plus as 'sys as sysdba' and logged into sql developer as system thats probably why. i did my alterations on sql developer successfully i tried to drop labuser on sql dev, but said the user was logged on and could not. so it logs on but then gets booted because of insufficient priv. seems like

Comment: @EdStevens it did not work :( updated post with screenshot

Comment: Edgar - my response was not directed at your problem.  It was directed at @Wernfried Domscheit and his assertion that there are steps beyond simply granting a role.  As pointed out by Luke Woodward, your error shows that you have some local processing- a logon trigger? -  going on that we are not privy to - you need to work that out with your DBA.